# jqPlot doesn't display at all with Rails-added bootstrap footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jqplot

I have a static page which displays a simple bar chart using jqplot, and when I throw that code into a Rails view it doesn't display anything.

1. The javascript does get called, because if I toss an alert into the
   showGraph() function it shows up on page load.
2. The server doesn't complain about not being able to find the javascript or CSS.
3. If I take the Rails-generated code and put it in the public folder to get
   it shown statically, the graph doesn't show up.
4. BUT, if I take out the line containing "script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"" in the footer, then the graph shows up
5. If I instead remove the call to jquery.min.js that precedes the jqplot includes, there is no difference in behavior.

EDIT:
 6. More fooling around shows that the graph won't appear if I include jquery.js any time after I include jquery.jqplot.min.js.

Is it possible to show this chart without messing with the footer? Is there a well-established way to do this correctly that I should know of?

Here is the Rails-generated HTML, minus some stuff which doesn't affect the behavior I'm talking about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    </style>
    <!--<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />


    <style type="text/css">
      .navbar .brand {
        //float: right;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        padding-top: 6px;
        //font-weight: 400;
      }
      .hero-unit h1 {
      //font-size:48px;
      }
      .hero-unit p {
      //font-size:24px;
        padding-top:12px;
      }
      .navbar .nav > li > a {
      line-height: 72px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      font-size: 18px;
      }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
      padding-top: 120px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      font-size: 14px;
      }
      footer {
      font-size:12px;
      }
      legend {margin-bottom: 10px;}
    </style>
    <style>
      table.cleanlink td a {text-decoration:none; color:inherit; display:block; padding:0px; height:100%;}
      table.cleanlink td a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:inherit;}
      div.data-scroller {width:910px; max-height:400px; overflow:scroll;}
    </style>
    <style>
      ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {display: block;}
      ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {margin-top: 0px;}
      //a.menu:after, .dropdown-toggle:after {content: none;}
    </style>



</head>
<body>



    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="brand" href="/home"><img src="/images/B4-l-s-m-h-i-2-273x80.png" /></a>

          <ul class="nav">
</ul>          <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="/account" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <!--<li class="divider"></li>-->
                  <li><a href="/signout" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a></li>
                </ul>
</li></ul>        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">


      <html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
  <script class="include" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/src/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
  <script class="include" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/src/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
  <script class="include" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/src/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

<script>

function showGraph() {
    var s1 = [20, 3, 2, 1];
    // Can specify a custom tick Array.
    // Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.
    var xticks = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
        // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
        // be applied to all series in the chart.
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'n', edgeTolerance: -15 },
            rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
        },
        axes: {
            // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: xticks
            },
            // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
            // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
            yaxis: {
                pad: 1.05,
                tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'}
            }
        }
    });
};
$(document).ready(showGraph);

  </script>
<div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:600px; "></div>
</html>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are loading the jquery library in three places in your document?

Why not add it to the asset pipeline?

In app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

`//= require jquery`

This should speed up pageloads and you won't have to include the script tags on every page.

Comment: Thanks. Would this slow my less fancy pages, though?

Comment: It's possible, but loading a minified jquery file is pretty fast regardless. I suppose requiring at the app level is more about code cleanliness than page load speed. Looking at my pageload, jquery asset took only 9ms to load.

If you have it included in the footer of the site, you are loading it on every page anyway, right? Why not just require it at the app level and then the jquery assets are available on every page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I did to get it working: removed the line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
```

which generates the offending line, from [appdir]/app/views/shared/_bootstrap2.html.erb (which generates the lines in the footer)

and put it into [appdir]/app/views/shared/_bootstrap.html.erb (which generates the lines in the header).

This isn't ideal since it means we're loading jquery before loading the rest of the page, so I'm still interested in a slicker solution.